# Trouble with multihead after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, radeon, intel, amd-graphics

After upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04, my 3 monitor multi-head display stopped working right.  After several hours of configuration, I've got two "almost there" `xorg.conf` files; one in which the first two displays work perfectly, but the third is unusable, another in which all three displays work, but the first two are on one screen `:0.0`, treated as a single large display (so maximizing windows span the two monitors, not what I want), and the third is on `:0.1`.

What I had in 14.04, and what I want now, is all three monitors as a single display `:0`, but treated as distinct monitors such that maximizing a window maximizes on just that monitor.

The hardware isn't the greatest, but obviously can support the configuration I want.  The first two monitors are attached to the two DVI ports of the ATI Radeon HD 3450 using the radeon kernel and xorg drivers, the third is attached to the on-board HDMI port of the Intel 4th Generation Integrated Graphics using the i915 kernel driver and the intel xorg driver.

This `xorg.conf` file results in the first two monitors working the way I want, but the third monitor doesn't work at all.  I don't understand how the second monitor is working at all with this config file, but it does:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
  Option "Xinerama" "off"
  Option "RandR" "on"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen         "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Left"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Center"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Right"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Option "Accel" "True"
    Option "SWcursor" "True"
    Option "TearFree" "True"
    Identifier  "ATI card"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option "Monitor-DVI-0" "Left"
    Option "Monitor-DVI-1" "Center"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Option "Accel" "True"
    Option "TearFree" "True"
    Option "SWcursor" "True"
    Identifier  "Intel IGA"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option "Monitor-HDMI1" "Right"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "ATI card"
    Monitor    "Left"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "ATI card"
    Monitor    "Center"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Intel IGA"
    Monitor    "Right"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

This `xorg.conf` gets all three monitors working, but on two separate X servers, which is definitely not what I want, but at least demonstrates that the hardware and software are all in place to drive all three heads:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
  Option "Xinerama" "off"
  Option "RandR" "on"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen         "Screen0" 0 0
 #  Screen         "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    Screen         "Screen2" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Left"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Center"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Right"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Option "Accel" "True"
    Option "SWcursor" "True"
    Option "TearFree" "True"
    Identifier  "ATI DVI0"
    Driver      "radeon"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    Option "Monitor-DVI-0" "Left"
    Option "Monitor-DVI-1" "Center"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Option "Accel" "True"
    Option "TearFree" "True"
    Option "SWcursor" "True"
    Option "DRI" "false"
    Identifier  "Intel IGA"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
    Option "Monitor-HDMI1" "Right"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "ATI DVI0"
    Monitor    "Left"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen2"
    Device     "Intel IGA"
    Monitor    "Right"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

With this configuration, `xrandr` run on `:0.0` shows the two heads of the ATI card, and on :0.1 shows the one head on the Intel "card".  I've been unable to find the configuration necessary to have all three heads show up on `:0.0`.

With no `xorg.conf` file X fails to start, displaying the troubleshooting/failsafe screen on the third monitor.  I've tried splitting out the ATI device into two device sections, one for each head (Screen 0 and Screen 1), but that also resulted in X failing to start.

Clearly I'm missing something.  Any ideas?

Post and comment limits are prohibitive for this issue, full configs and logs are at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tptxeVkP7dXlRhzHCqQaJNCwHMMWkJEB

Comment: I've got the best experience with the autoconf of Xorg in 16.04; it just works out of the box (with an Intel integrated controller) without any `xorg.conf`. So, what are the errors you get when starting Xorg without the config file (see `/var/log/Xorg.*.log`, whatever is the newest of these)? Perhaps you also try with a clean `/etc/X11` dir.

Comment: As I'd said, with no xorg.conf (just the ubuntu provided /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d) the autoconfig simply fails, the ultimate error is "No devices detected." after trying the intel, ati, modesetting, fbdev, and vesa drivers. 
It then reverts to the failsafe configuration, which just pops up the configuration dialog (which also fails in interesting and unpredictable ways). That configuration does somehow succeed to initialise the display with fbdev driver.

Comment: Allright, but **what are the actual, complete log messages?!**

Comment: The actual, complete log messages are far longer than the 600 character comment limit (with no xorg.conf it yields 9101 for Xorg.0.log, 31818 for Xorg.failsafe.log).  I attempted to edit the post to add them there, but they are also longer than the 30000 character post limit.

I've uploaded the logs and config files to https://goo.gl/pmh444